# Chrome 77 LayoutNG breaks my float layout

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-float

I have a website that I designed based on the "Holy Grail" layout described in this [A List Apart post](https://alistapart.com/article/holygrail/). A recent Chrome update broke it. You can see the results on the [example page](https://alistapart.github.io/code-samples/holygrail/example_3.html) for the article (I also made it into [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sw9pax17/)). Open it in Firefox to see what it should like and in Chrome to see what's happening now.

I realize that this technique is super dated, and I have plans in place to redesign it with Flexbox. But, that will take time, and I was hoping to get it working again quickly in the meantime while I work on a redesign. You can read more about LayoutNG on [this page](https://www.chromium.org/blink/layoutng).

Does anyone know any tips and tricks to fix this? Is there a Chrome bug already open that I can follow?

**Update:** I decided to test it in Canary (v79), and the layout works perfectly there. It's still broken in Beta though (v78). So, I could wait until the current Canary gets released, but that won't be until December according to [current estimates](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/schedule). So, I would still like to find a quick fix between now and then if one is available.

Here's some code to make SO happy:

```
SO won't let me post a link to jsFiddle without code...smart
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to not be that hard to reimplement the layout with Flexbox. So, I just did some good old fashioned user agent sniffing to detect broken Chrome versions and load a small CSS snippet to override the appropriate styles.